# Output of diskutil info: dlopen(...): code signature in (...) not valid for use in process

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, kernel-extensions

When I run `diskutil info` on an external drive, the output contains errors that make me wonder if I need to be concerned about the security, or at least the stability of my computer:

```
2019-10-03 11:03:06.960 diskutil[33363:4183029] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/SATSMARTLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SATSMARTLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/SATSMARTLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SATSMARTLib, 0x0106): code signature in (/System/Library/Extensions/SATSMARTLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SATSMARTLib) not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
2019-10-03 11:03:06.960 diskutil[33363:4183029] Cannot find function pointer SATSMARTLibFactory for factory 3AD527ED in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fa76dc41210 </System/Library/Extensions/SATSMARTLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
```

Full output:

```
diskutil info /dev/disk4
   Device Identifier:         disk4
   Device Node:               /dev/disk4
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk4
   Device / Media Name:       WDC WD40NMZW

   Volume Name:               RW-WD-Silver
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /Volumes/RW-WD-Silver

   Content (IOContent):       Apple_HFS
   File System Personality:   Journaled HFS+
   Type (Bundle):             hfs
   Name (User Visible):       Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
   Journal:                   Journal size 311296 KB at offset 0x3a3a000
   Owners:                    Disabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       Yes
   Booter Disk:               disk2s3
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  USB
2019-10-03 11:03:06.960 diskutil[33363:4183029] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/SATSMARTLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SATSMARTLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/SATSMARTLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SATSMARTLib, 0x0106): code signature in (/System/Library/Extensions/SATSMARTLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SATSMARTLib) not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
2019-10-03 11:03:06.960 diskutil[33363:4183029] Cannot find function pointer SATSMARTLibFactory for factory 3AD527ED in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fa76dc41210 </System/Library/Extensions/SATSMARTLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Volume UUID:               9D6E9516
   Disk / Partition UUID:     00010CBB

   Disk Size:                 4.0 TB (4000040615936 Bytes) (exactly 7812579328 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        4.0 TB (4000040615936 Bytes) (exactly 7812579328 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Used Space:         4.0 TB (3958573326336 Bytes) (exactly 7731588528 512-Byte-Units) (99.0%)
   Volume Free Space:         41.5 GB (41467289600 Bytes) (exactly 80990800 512-Byte-Units) (1.0%)
   Allocation Block Size:     8192 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          No

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Virtual:                   Yes

   This disk is a Core Storage Logical Volume (LV).  Core Storage Information:
   LV UUID:                   00010CBB
   LVF UUID:                  1BC2F8A8
   LVG UUID:                  46789CD7
   PV UUID (disk):            5BCFA56F (disk2s2)
   Fusion Drive:              No
   Encrypted:                 Yes
```

(I trimmed all identifiers for brevity)

A google search didn't give results for this error, although it did reveal that `/System/Library/Extensions/SATSMARTLib.plugin` seems to be a kernel driver that [extends the standard driver behaviour by providing access to drive
SMART data for USB and FireWire drives](https://github.com/kasbert/OS-X-SAT-SMART-Driver).

I didn't install this, so it must have been installed by a third party, presumably a tool I once installed using brew or downloaded from the web.

What does this error mean, and how do I identify which package installed it? The readme for the extension has instructions on how to uninstall, but since I didn't install it I'd first like to know where it came from.

Comment: Hi Rolf! I just want to let you know that I've also encountered this issue and have been researching the answer. I think I know now, but I want to get more confirmation before posting the answer in full. (In a nutshell: the error message is disconcerting, but in this case, it's very likely nothing to worry about.)

Comment: Rolf: If you navigate to `/System/Library/Extensions` in the Finder, and "Get info" on `SATSMARTDriver.kext` and `SATSMARTLib.plugin`, what is the version number displayed for each?